# Is it possible to have browser cache .php file with querystring in .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, browser-cache

My website loading speed is too low in pingdom tool. It has approximately 65 cache validator errors. And so i have used the below code in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access 7 days"
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest  "access 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType images/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType images/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType images/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType images/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType img/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType img/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType img/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType img/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/html  "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf    "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

But it again shows error in php file with querystring like the below

http://www.example.com/img.php?test=sometext&img=https://images.pexels.com/photos/56866/garden-rose-red-pink-56866.jpeg

Please anyone tell me how do i set cache for the above url format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is img.php ? An image pre-processor script? If so, you'll have to set expiration http headers within it, before dispatching the image itself.

Comment: Try looking at the actual headers sent when accessing the image. Open up your web developer tools (e.g. Ctrl-Shift-I for Chrome), click on the Network tab and click on the request for the image. It should show you the response headers.

Comment: img.php file has the resizing code. As there is more third party images in my website, i have resize those images.

Comment: When i add the below php code to add etag and last modified headers in .htaccess file. The error goes away.                                                      
      $file = 'img.php';
   $last_modified_time = filemtime($file); 
    $etag = md5_file($file); 

    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", $last_modified_time)." GMT"); 
    header("Etag: $etag"); 

    if (@strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) == $last_modified_time || 
        trim($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) == $etag) { 
        header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified"); 
        exit; 
    }